# when erlang in detached model ,where is error log?

Tags: erlang

when add detached ,can not find error info  ,eg "Can't set long node name"

```
root@test:~# erl -name test
{error_logger,{{2015,3,11},{12,14,0}},"Can't set long node name!\nPlease check your configuration\n",[]}
```

......

```
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{k
root@test:~#
root@test:~#
root@test:~#
root@test:~#
root@test:~#
root@test:~#
root@test:~# erl -name test -detached
root@test:~#
root@test:~#
root@test:~# ag Please erl_crash.dump
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While startnig erl sends all logs to standard output. Only after the [kernel](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html) application comes up you can use [error_logger](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html) to redirect to file or any other custom log handler.
The errors which occur even before kernel application is started (For example in your case) you cannot log it to file by any options. 
To do this you can use [run_erl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/run_erl.html) (linux) or [start_erl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/start_erl.html)(windows)

```
run_erl [-daemon] pipe_dir/ log_dir "exec command [command_arguments]"

run_erl -daemon /tmp/ /home/abc "exec erl -name test"
```

You can attach to the above started erl using the following

```
to_erl /tmp/
```

The log_dir will contain the logs run_erl.log and erlang.log.1. You can see the error message if not started properly in erlang.log.N

For details you can check the above links.

Answer (score 0):

> -detached
>    Starts the Erlang runtime system detached from the system console. Useful for running daemons and backgrounds processes. Implies
>   -noinput.